# gdal created tiles for the U.S. are displayed south of equator

Tags: gdal, tilecache

I am using gdal_translate to convert a map in spheroid meters to EPSG:900913.  I then use gdal2tiles.py to create tiles.
I am centering my googlemaps using Lat and Long in the central U.S.. I am overlaying the tiles onto Googlemaps.   The tiles are displayed south of the Equator?  How do I get the tiles to center over the U.S.

Comment: Feels like switched lat/long order is some part of your process.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! "spheroid meters" doesn't make sense. What's the original coordinate reference system? Can you edit your question with the extents before and after gdal_translate?